# from _dlib_pybind11 import * ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dlib_pybind11'

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I actually working on a face recognition project but getting an error such as:

```py
from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dlib_pybind11'
```

Please help I'll appreciate any bits of help.

- OS:windows 10
- Python 3.8
- dlib 19.18.0
- face_recognition 1.3.0
- NumPy 1.18.4

My code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition

imElon = face_recognition.load_image_file("ImageBasic/ElonMusk.jpg")
imElon = cv2.cvtColor(imElon.cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

imTest = face_recognition.load_image_file("ImageBasic/ElonTest.jpg")
imTest = cv2.cvtColor(imTest.cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

faceLoc = face_recognition.face_locations(imElon)[0]
encodeElon = face_recognition.face_encodings(imElon)[0]
print(faceLoc)

cv2.imshow('Elon Musk', imElon)
cv2.imshow('Elon Test', imTest)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by uninstalling and installing dlib

Answer (score 0):

face_recognition package is based on dlib and it is problematic package. Why don't you use deepface?

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
resp = DeepFace.verify(img1_path = "ImageBasic/ElonMusk.jpg", img2_path = "ImageBasic/ElonTest.jpg")
print(resp["verified"])
```

It builds VGG-Face model by default but you can manage the face recognition model backend. The following face recognition models are wrapped within the framework. Currently, VGG-Face, Google FaceNet and ArcFace overperform.

```
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'ArcFace', 'Dlib']
DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[1])
```

Notice that it wraps Dlib as well. But you have to install dlib as a prerequisite.

Comment: hi dear, I fixed my problem. Yes, I'll try deep face if it's effective and high quality to recognize.   Thank you for answer))

Comment: Hi dear, Yes I did as you wrote it worked. Thank you so much. Appreciate it!