# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dlib_pybind11' for face recognition

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition, dlib, modulenotfounderror

I tried this code but was getting the error:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition

imgEme = face_recognition.load_image_file('Image/Emeka1.jpg')
imgEme = cv2.cvtColor(imgEme,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
imgTest = face_recognition.load_image_file('Image/Emeka2.jpg')
imgTest = cv2.cvtColor(imgEme,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

cv2.imgShow('Chukwuemeka',imgEme)
cv2.imgShow('Chukwuemeka Test',imgTest)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\New-face-reg\new-face-reg.py", line 3, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "C:\New-face-reg\.venv\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "C:\New-face-reg\.venv\Lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 4, in <module>
    import dlib
  File "C:\New-face-reg\.venv\Lib\site-packages\dlib\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dlib_pybind11'
```

I have installed cmake and dlib (`dlib-19.24.1.dist-info`), please what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried [uninstalling and installing again dlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73745735/7396613)?

Comment: first, install Wheel [link](https://pypi.org/project/wheel/) then try again.

Comment: @M.K i did that but the same error occured

Comment: @lareb I have done it but no change